# YouCompleteMe breaks auto-indent for LaTeX in vim

Tags: vim, latex, vim-plugin

In LaTeX, I was used to typing

```
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Foo
        \item Bar
\end{enumerate}
```

And before typing `Bar`, the second `\item` would jump back to the correct indentation level.
After installing YouCompleteMe, this no longer works. I have to manually reformat the text.

I am very happy with YouCompleteMe, but I also don't want to give up on the auto-indent for vim. What should I do?

Comment: How about opening an issue at YCM's tracker, so that it can be fixed?!

Comment: Well, I thought maybe there was an option I missed, or something like that. If this is a real bug, then I'll definitely do that.

Comment: @jmc, if it's a bug they will fix it, if it's an overlooked option they will tell you.

Comment: @romainl — That's not really in line with their guidelines for using the issue tracker. Anyway, here goes nothing (-; <https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/issues/1244>

Comment: @jmc, From the README: *"If you have questions about the plugin or need help, please use the ycm-users mailing list, don't create issues on the tracker. The tracker is for bug reports and feature requests."* Use their issue tracker or their mailing list as you see fit but not a generic site like stack overflow.